# iOS: UIImageView doesn't respond to tap gestures between animations

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a multiple images to show in imageview using cross dissolve animation and taping on image displays detail about image. Following is the code working but tap on imageview is failing when it's animating from one image to another.

Code for attaching single tap gesture recogniser to UIImageview and starting animation timer.

```
    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.singleTapGestureRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails)];
    self.singleTapGestureRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.singleTapGestureRecogniser.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:self.singleTapGestureRecogniser];

    [self startAnimationTimer];

- (void)startAnimationTimer
{
    if(!self.timer && ![self.timer isValid]) {
        self.timer  =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                target:self
                                selector:@selector(startAnimation)
                                userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
        [self.timer fire];
    }
}
```

Single tap on imageview works fine unless following code is executing! I have to tap 3-4 times to open details about image.

```
- (void)startAnimation
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^ {
                        currentImageIndex = ++currentImageIndex % self.images.count;
                        [self.imageView setImage:[[self.images objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex] image]];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    }
     ];
}
```

Could someone please suggest me how to get rid of this issue please.

Comment: disable userinteraction while animating and enable after complete the animation.

Comment: I don't want to disable user interaction. I want to recognise tap events at any time including while animating.

Comment: can you show me the crash log?

Comment: I didn't say it crashes! Anyway it got solved. Check Hermione333 answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in the options like so

```
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                    animations:^ {
                        currentImageIndex = ++currentImageIndex % self.images.count;
                        [self.imageView setImage:[[self.images objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex] image]];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    }
     ];
```

Comment: sorry I tried accepting it immediately but SO asked me to wait 5 minutes!